# What happens when process call signal on a semaphore?

Tags: operating-system, mutex, semaphore, critical-section

What will happen if a process call signal on a semaphore.

Say the semaphore count is 3. Processes P1, P2, P3 called wait on the semaphore and entered the Critical Section.
P4, P5, P6 also called wait , but since the semaphore count is already 0 they will be waiting in the wait queue of the semaphore.
Now P7 came and called signal(), will the process waiting (P4, P5 or P6) for the semaphore woken up ? It its woken up then its an error right because semaphore count is 2 but p1, p2 and p3 have not left the critical section.

Answer (score 0):

Only one of the threads that is sleeping (one of P4, P5, and P6) will be woken up. You say the semaphore count is 2, but it's actually 1, right?

This behavior is correct because P7 called `signal`. Any thread can call `signal` on a semaphore even if it didn't initially call `wait` on the semaphore. This is different from a mutex, which *does* have a concept of ownership (e.g. a thread cannot call `unlock` on a mutex if it never called `lock` on the mutex).

Comment: You say the semaphore count is 2, but it's actually 1, right? -- Yes thats right, thanks for correcting.

Comment: if P7 called signal, then there will be 4 processes active or in the CS right. but the semaphore count declared is 3, which means only 3 can be active. This concept is defeated right ?

Comment: @user2231999 The number you specify when creating a semaphore is its initial count. It is **not** a maximum count or a maximum number of threads that can ever be in the critical section, since as you point out, you can call `signal` on the semaphore to either exceed the initial count or allow more threads into the critical section. So you're right - 4 different threads can go into the critical section in that scenario. That is not considered incorrect behavior since P7 did call `signal`.